# Format String every N characters depending on the length of the String

Tags: swift

everyone, I need to live update character by character a String/TextField depending on the length of the String.

Eg: If user inserts 43041058, it should change to 4.304.105-8,
else if user inserts one more number (12 total characters) 430410582, it should update to 43.041.058-2.

Real Time Execution eg:

```
Step | User Input
1 | 4.
2 | 4.3
3 | 4.30
4 | 4.304.
5 | 4.304.1
6 | 4.304.10
7 | 4.304.105
8 | 4.304.105-8
9 | 43.041.058-2
```

The important thing is that the textField updates itself for each Character pressed, the closet I've got its to make it work only for 12 positions not for 11.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    rutFormatter()
    }

    func rutFormatter() {
        textRut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VCLogin.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
var newRut = String()
        for (index, character) in (textField.text?.enumerated())! {
            if index % 2 == 0 {
                if index != 0 && index % 2 == 0 {
                    switch index {
                    case 2:
                        if character != "." {
                            newRut.append(".")
                        }
                    case 10:
                        if character != "-" {
                            newRut.append("-")
                        }
                    default:
                        print("Default")
                    }
                }

                if index != 0 && index % 3 == 0 {
                    switch index {
                    case 6:
                        if character != "." {
                            newRut.append(".")
                        }
                    default:
                        print("Default")
                    }
                }
            }


            newRut.append(String(character))
        }
        textField.text = newRut
}
```

Comment: The way I would code this is write a function that transforms ANY input string into a display version, capture each keypress into a class variable (without the formatting), use that as the input to the function, display the output in the text field.

Comment: What notation is this, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work.

```
let mask = "X.XXX.XXX-X"
let mask2 = "XX.XXX.XXX-X"

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let string = textField.text
    let number = formattedNumber(number: textField.text!)
    textField.text = number
    print(string)
}

private func formattedNumber(number: String) -> String {
    var cleanPhoneNumber = number.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()

    var result = ""
    var index = cleanPhoneNumber.startIndex
    var fieldMask: String!
    if number.count < 12 {
        fieldMask = mask
    }else {
        fieldMask = mask2
    }
    for ch in fieldMask.characters {
        if index == cleanPhoneNumber.endIndex {
            break
        }
        if ch == "X" {
            result.append(cleanPhoneNumber[index])
            index = cleanPhoneNumber.index(after: index)
        } else {
            result.append(ch)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. It's best to provide an explanation of what was wrong and how the answers solves the issue.

Comment: Additionally, if you're copying from another answer, you might want to update the var names inside the code.